# How can I update an android app's certificate and version code?

Tags: android

Earlier I had made an app using Appsgeyser website. This is a very basic apps that just converts my website into an app. But I see that they are serving annoying and aggressive ads on the app and because of that many users are uninstalling the app. Now I have remade the app using a different software but when I try to update the apk it shows error that the existing APKs were signed with different certificate(s) and fingerprint(s) and also that the new version code should be higher. I have the previous apk. Is it possible to somehow update the certificates and version code in new apk? I don't want to upload a fresh app and lose existing users. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not without the old certificate that you signed the first APK with. You'll also need a password for it.
If you don't have the old certificate and password, you may want to start a new app.
If you find it and you can't remember the password there are bruteforce tools that could crack the password for you if it's simple enough.
Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thanks. Will this third-party website I created the old app with give me the certificate and password if I ask them? What do you think? It was a free account.